# Visual Studio 2010 command to edit file in same instance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, command-line

I need to open a list of files in Visual Studio from command line, but in the same instance.

I used:

```
devenv.exe /Command Edit fileName
```

but this opens a new instance for every file. It is possible to edit the file in an already opened instance from command line?

Comment: I solved this by adding the file list as argument. Please close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a list of

```
"devenv.exe file1" ... "devenv.exe fileN"
```

I used:

```
"devenv.exe file1 ... fileN"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file-associations are set correctly, this works:

```
start filename
```

Comment: Golden. Did not know this one!